# Letting another Table appear inside of an already existing Table via Button Click

Tags: javascript, php, html, css

I got an HTML Table with a Button on the left side.

[image]

What I would like to achieve is that by using the Button the Table splits below that row and another table with different columns and rows appears with the full width of the original table.. basically the new table pushes the rest of the original table down the page.

What would be a solid approach to this without using any big libraries/frameworks?

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <th></th>
        <th>Lieferant</th>
        <th>urspüngliches Lieferdatum</th>
        <th>Liefer-ID</th>
    </tr>
    <tr class="new_tr verspaetet">
        <td><input type="image" src="./img/down-arrow.png" /></td>
        <td>Müller GmbH</td>
        <td>20.10.2022</td>
        <td>12384123</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="new_tr">
        <td><input type="image" src="./img/down-arrow.png" /></td>
        <td>Wasser GmbH</td>
        <td>heute</td>
        <td>12385533</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="new_tr">
        <td><input type="image" src="./img/down-arrow.png" /></td>
        <td>Grill GmbH</td>
        <td>heute</td>
        <td>94728544</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="new_tr">
        <td><input type="image" src="./img/down-arrow.png" /></td>
        <td>Bier GmbH</td>
        <td>heute</td>
        <td>82375440</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="new_tr">
        <td><input type="image" src="./img/down-arrow.png" /></td>
        <td>Pflaumen GmbH</td>
        <td>heute</td>
        <td>52469874</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="new_tr">
        <td><input type="image" src="./img/down-arrow.png" /></td>
        <td>Bananen GmbH</td>
        <td>heute</td>
        <td>16543897</td>
    </tr>
</tr>
```

```

Comment: The best option is to simply not use tables. Divs would work best and would be easier to work with because you could wrap each row in a div and add after it etc.

Comment: You could add a new row with a single cell the width of the table and put the new table in that cell.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, generate the inner table in a separate row of the table you have, and initially hide it. Something like:

```
<tr style="display: none">
    <td></td>
    <td colspan="100"><table>
        <tr><th>Other</th><th>Table</th><th>Comes</th><th>Here</th></tr>
        <tr><td>12</td><td>123.33</td><td>green</td><td>99</td></tr>
        <tr><td>13</td><td>387.41</td><td>red</td><td>87</td></tr>
        <tr><td>14</td><td>277.10</td><td>blue</td><td>28</td></tr>
    </table></td>
</tr>
```

The empty `td` serves to get a bit of indentation of the inner table. The `colspan` attribute ensures that the table occupies the remaining column space of the outer table.

Once you have those inner tables embedded in your HTML, you can add some JavaScript to respond to a click on the arrow cell. Give that arrow cell a specific class so a click on it can be easily recognised.

Here is how that looks:

```js
const table = document.querySelector("table");
table.addEventListener("click", function (e) {
    const td = e.target;
    if (td.classList.contains("expander")) {
        const style = td.parentNode.nextElementSibling.style;
        const wasOpen = !style.display;
        console.log(wasOpen);
        style.display = wasOpen ? "none" : "";
        td.textContent = wasOpen ? "▼" : "▲";
    }
});
```

```css
table { border-collapse: collapse }
th { background: silver;  }
td, th { border: 1px solid; }
.new_tr > td:first-child { cursor: pointer }
td > table { width: 100% }
```

```html
<table>
    <tr>
        <th></th>
        <th>Lieferant</th>
        <th>urspüngliches Lieferdatum</th>
        <th>Liefer-ID</th>
    </tr>
    <tr class="new_tr verspaetet">
        <td class="expander">▼</td>
        <td>Müller GmbH</td>
        <td>20.10.2022</td>
        <td>12384123</td>
    </tr>
    <tr style="display: none">
        <td></td>
        <td colspan="100"><table>
            <tr><th>Other</th><th>Table</th><th>Comes</th><th>Here</th></tr>
            <tr><td>12</td><td>123.33</td><td>green</td><td>99</td></tr>
            <tr><td>13</td><td>387.41</td><td>red</td><td>87</td></tr>
            <tr><td>14</td><td>277.10</td><td>blue</td><td>28</td></tr>
        </table></td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="new_tr">
        <td class="expander">▼</td>
        <td>Wasser GmbH</td>
        <td>heute</td>
        <td>12385533</td>
    </tr>
    <tr style="display: none">
        <td></td>
        <td colspan="100"><table>
            <tr><th>Other</th><th>Table</th><th>Comes</th><th>Here</th></tr>
            <tr><td>12</td><td>123.33</td><td>green</td><td>99</td></tr>
            <tr><td>13</td><td>387.41</td><td>red</td><td>87</td></tr>
            <tr><td>14</td><td>277.10</td><td>blue</td><td>28</td></tr>
        </table></td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="new_tr">
        <td class="expander">▼</td>
        <td>Grill GmbH</td>
        <td>heute</td>
        <td>94728544</td>
    </tr>
    <tr style="display: none">
        <td></td>
        <td colspan="100"><table>
            <tr><th>Other</th><th>Table</th><th>Comes</th><th>Here</th></tr>
            <tr><td>12</td><td>123.33</td><td>green</td><td>99</td></tr>
            <tr><td>13</td><td>387.41</td><td>red</td><td>87</td></tr>
            <tr><td>14</td><td>277.10</td><td>blue</td><td>28</td></tr>
        </table></td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="new_tr">
        <td class="expander">▼</td>
        <td>Bier GmbH</td>
        <td>heute</td>
        <td>82375440</td>
    </tr>
    <tr style="display: none">
        <td></td>
        <td colspan="100"><table>
            <tr><th>Other</th><th>Table</th><th>Comes</th><th>Here</th></tr>
            <tr><td>12</td><td>123.33</td><td>green</td><td>99</td></tr>
            <tr><td>13</td><td>387.41</td><td>red</td><td>87</td></tr>
            <tr><td>14</td><td>277.10</td><td>blue</td><td>28</td></tr>
        </table></td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="new_tr">
        <td class="expander">▼</td>
        <td>Pflaumen GmbH</td>
        <td>heute</td>
        <td>52469874</td>
    </tr>
    <tr style="display: none">
        <td></td>
        <td colspan="100"><table>
            <tr><th>Other</th><th>Table</th><th>Comes</th><th>Here</th></tr>
            <tr><td>12</td><td>123.33</td><td>green</td><td>99</td></tr>
            <tr><td>13</td><td>387.41</td><td>red</td><td>87</td></tr>
            <tr><td>14</td><td>277.10</td><td>blue</td><td>28</td></tr>
        </table></td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="new_tr">
        <td class="expander">▼</td>
        <td>Bananen GmbH</td>
        <td>heute</td>
        <td>16543897</td>
    </tr>
    <tr style="display: none">
        <td></td>
        <td colspan="100"><table>
            <tr><th>Other</th><th>Table</th><th>Comes</th><th>Here</th></tr>
            <tr><td>12</td><td>123.33</td><td>green</td><td>99</td></tr>
            <tr><td>13</td><td>387.41</td><td>red</td><td>87</td></tr>
            <tr><td>14</td><td>277.10</td><td>blue</td><td>28</td></tr>
        </table></td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: this is excactly what i was looking for!! Thanks <3 We are doing a 8 man project for uni and you saved us quite bit!

Answer (score -2):

Tables are not worth the hassle, learning [`display: grid`](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/complete-guide-grid/) will save you pain and time

Comment: The data is clearly tabular data. To not use a table is to disrespect all accessibility technology users who would benefit from the information made available by the table mark up.